# Why does a backlash appear before every apostrophe in a PHP email?

Tags: php, regex, forms, email, html-email

For some reason, a () backlash appear before every (') apostrophe when sending a HTML formatted email through the PHP mail(); function. It's not a typo or anything similar. I have checked with other symbols and it only occurs with the apostrophe. It's so weird. It happens within the parameter $message from the form textarea (Note it's not the whole content, as long as I know as my regex doesn't allow apostrophes anywhere else). Could this have to do with the UTF-8 encoding? It's just so weird. Has it ever happened to anyone else and is there any solution to it? It's not a big problem, it's just not a usual one.

```
 $to = 'example@email.com';
            $subject = "Hey, you've got a new message!";
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: <example@email.com>' . "\r\n";
            $content = "<html><head><style>
               .bold {
                  font-weight: bold;
               }
               .contiguous {
                  display: inline-block;
               }
               .correct-spacing {
                  white-space: pre-wrap;
               }
               .grey {
                  color: #373737;
               }
               .lilac {
                  color: #7b68ee;
               }
               </style></head><body>
               <div class='bold contiguous lilac'>From:&nbsp;</div><div class='contiguous grey'>$name</div><br/>
               <div class='bold contiguous lilac'>E-mail:&nbsp;</div><div class='contiguous grey'>$email</div><br/>
               <div class='bold contiguous lilac'>Phone:&nbsp;</div><div class='contiguous grey'>$phone</div><br/><br/>
               <div class='correct-spacing grey'>$message</div>
               </body></html>";
            mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
            echo 'Your message has been sent. Thank you!';
```

Example of received email:

> From: Name Example
>
> E-mail: example@email.com
>
> Phone: +123456789
>
> Hi there,
>
> This is a test. Let\'s hope it works.
>
> Regards

Comment: Check `magic_quotes_gpc` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) enabled; this feature was deprecated in 5.3 and altogether removed in 5.4, but older versions would still have it enabled by default.

Read [this article](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) about how you can disable magic quotes in your existing environment if you can't upgrade your installation.

You can also use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove the backslashes before sending the message.

```
$clean_message = stripslashes ($content);
mail($to, $subject, clean_message, $headers);
```

Comment: Never heard of this before (I am new to PHP). It worked. I used your second option as this was a little thing. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help you!